# Evaluate $\int_{1/10}^{1/2}\left(\frac{\sin{x}-\sin{3x}+\sin{5x}}{\cos{x}+\cos{3x}+\cos{5x}}\right)^2dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

How can I evaluate the following integral?

> $$\int_{1/10}^{1/2}\left(\frac{\sin{x}-\sin{3x}+\sin{5x}}{\cos{x}+\cos{3x}+\cos{5x}}\right)^2dx$$

I notice that the numerator and the denominator are very similar. So my direction is to evaluate this integral by substitution. However, I cannot find a suitable substitution so that the integral can be nice.

Comment: An application of the tangent half-angle identity$$\frac{\sin\alpha+\sin\beta}{\cos\alpha+\cos\beta} = \tan\frac{\alpha+\beta}2$$takes care of this.  See my answer below. $\qquad$

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe it is useful to notice that

> $$ \frac{\sin x-\sin(3x)+\sin(5x)}{\cos(x)+\cos(3x)+\cos(5x)}=\color{red}{\tan x}\tag{1}$$

and $\int \tan^2 x\,dx = -x+\tan(x).$ In terms of [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials), $(1)$ is equivalent to:
$$ x\cdot\left(1-U_2(x)+U_4(x)\right) = T_1(x)+T_3(x)+T_5(x)\tag{2}$$
that is straightforward to check.

Comment: (+1) That's just brilliant. How did you notice that, out of curiosity? The simplest way I know to discover it would be use trig formulae, or equivalently to look up a few Chebyshev polynomials of both kinds.

Comment: @Semiclassical: Chebyshev polynomials, exactly, you spotted me :D

Comment: Oh it is true! But its there a proof why they are equivalence?

Comment: @YYLam Probably the simplest way is to write $\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$, then multiply both denominators out and simplify. What's left should follow from the product-to-sums identities.

Comment: @YYLam: I added my derivation, but Semiclassical's one through the sum formulas is just as fine.

Comment: I don't know much about Chebyshev polynomials. But I just manage to prove it using $2\sin{A}\sin{B}=\sin{(A+B)}+\sin{(A-B)}$, thus $\sin{x}-\sin{3x}+\sin{5x}=\frac{\sin{6x}}{2\cos{x}}$

Comment: @YYLam: exactly, that is the elementary (equivalent) way.

Comment: @Semiclassical : Another way of noticing that identity is that it follows from the tangent half-angle formula $$\frac{\sin\alpha+\sin\beta}{\cos\alpha+\cos\beta} = \tan\frac{\alpha+\beta}2.$$  See my answer posted here. $\qquad$

Comment: It seems as if, in general, $$(-1)^n\tan(x)=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^i\sin((2i+1)x)}{\sum_{i=0}^{n}\cos((2i+1)x)}$$

Answer (score 7):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\, #2 \,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\sin\pars{x} - \sin\pars{3x} + \sin\pars{5x}}
\\[3mm] = &\
\Im\sum_{k = 0}^{2}\pars{-1}^{k}\expo{\ic\pars{2k + 1}x} =
\Im\bracks{\expo{\ic x}\,
{\pars{-\expo{2\ic x}}^{3} - 1 \over -\expo{2\ic x} - 1}} =
\sin\pars{3x}\,{\cos\pars{3x} \over \color{#f00}{\cos\pars{x}}}\tag{1}
\\
&\ --------------------------------
\\
&\color{#f00}{\cos\pars{x} + \cos\pars{3x} + \cos\pars{5x}}
\\[3mm] = &\
\Re\sum_{k = 0}^{2}\expo{\ic\pars{2k + 1}x} =
\Re\bracks{\expo{\ic x}\,
{\pars{\expo{2\ic x}}^{3} - 1 \over \expo{2\ic x} - 1}} =
\cos\pars{3x}\,{\sin\pars{3x} \over \color{#f00}{\sin\pars{x}}}\tag{2}
\\
&\ --------------------------------
\\ &\
\mbox{Then,}\quad {\pars{1} \over \pars{2}} = \color{#f00}{\tan\pars{x}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 5):

Someone's suggested Chebyshev polynomials.  I hadn't thought of that, but I know the tangent half-angle formula:
$$
\frac{\sin\alpha+\sin\beta}{\cos\alpha+\cos\beta} = \tan\frac{\alpha+\beta}2.
$$
From that we get
$$
\frac{\sin(-3x) + \sin(5x)}{\cos(-3x) + \cos(5x)} = \tan x.
$$
Since $\cos(-3x)=\cos(3x)$, that's the same as the function that gets squared except it's missing the two functions of $1\cdot x$.  But if
$$
\frac a b = \frac c d
$$
then both are equal to
$$
\frac{a+b}{c+d}
$$
and that can be applied in the case where we have
$$
\frac a b = \frac{\sin(-3x) + \sin(5x)}{\cos(-3x) + \cos(5x)} = \tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} = \frac c d.
$$
with the ultimate conclusion that the fraction that gets squared under the integral sign is $\tan x$.

Answer (score 0):

Using product-to-sum formula, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
2 \cos x(\sin x-\sin 3 x+\sin 5 x) = & \sin 2 x-(\sin 4 x+\sin 2 x)+(\sin 6 x+\sin 4 x) \\
= & \sin 6 x \cdots (1)
\end{aligned}
$$
and
$$
\begin{aligned}
2 \sin x(\cos x+\cos 3 x+\cos 5 x) = & \sin 2 x+(\sin 4 x-\sin 2 x)+(\sin 6 x-\sin 4 x) \\
= & \sin 6 x \cdots (2) 
\end{aligned}
$$
$(1)\div(2)$ yields
$$
\frac{\sin x-\sin 3 x+\sin 5 x}{\cos x+\cos 3 x+\cos 5 x}=\tan x
$$